# How to count revisited customer ( more than 1 time) in laravel using query builder?

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-query-builder

I need to count revisited customer in one month. It means need to count customer_id has more than one entry in table within a month.

My query is showing only the total customer.

```
$count_customer_current_month = DB::table("customer_entry")->whereRaw('MONTH(date) = ?', 
                                [$currentMonth])->count();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `group by customer_id having COUNT(customer_id) > 1`

```php
$entry_customers = DB::table("customer_entry")
   ->whereRaw('MONTH(date) = ?', [$currentMonth])
   ->groupBy('customer_id')
   ->havingRaw("COUNT(customer_id) > 1")
   ->selectRaw('COUNT(customer_id) AS entry_count, customer_id');
```

If you want to get how many this customers:

```php
$entry_customers->get()->count() // count the collections.
```

Or use subquery to get the customers count:

```php
DB::table(DB::raw("({$entry_customers->getSql()}) AS entry_customer"))
   ->mergeBindings($entry_customers)
   ->count();
```

Comment: DB::table("customer_entry")->whereRaw('MONTH(date) = ?',[$currentMonth])->havingRaw('COUNT(customer_id) > 1')->count();            its counting only total entry, no effect of having COUNT(customer_id) > 1

Comment: i used your code as it is but not working. I just need number.

Comment: @kapildevsharma you don't have the `group by`

Comment: out put of your code is very strange.  its [{"COUNT(customer_id)":"5"},{"COUNT(customer_id)":"2"},{"COUNT(customer_id)":"2"},{"COUNT(customer_id)":"2"},{"COUNT(customer_id)":"6"},{"COUNT(customer_id)":"2"},{"COUNT(customer_id)":"2"},{"COUNT(customer_id)":"2"},{"COUNT(customer_id)":"3"},{"COUNT(customer_id)":"2"},{"COUNT(customer_id)":"2"},{"COUNT(customer_id)":"2"},{"COUNT(customer_id)":"2"},{"COUNT(customer_id)":"2"},{"COUNT(customer_id)":"5"},{"COUNT(customer_id)":"2"},{"COUNT(customer_id)":"2"},{"COUNT(customer_id)":"2"},{"COUNT(customer_id)":"2"}]

Comment: Why customers id is 2. while 2 is not  related to any customer_id

Comment: @kapildevsharma  you can use `->selectRaw('COUNT(customer_id) as entry_count, customer_id')`, then you will know what it is.

Comment: Can you write complete query, please. it will easy to understand.

Comment: @kapildevsharma I have updated it, COUNT(customer_id) means the customer_id's  entry count.

Comment: its showing revisit no of each revisited customer, its partially ok, but how to count total revisited customers ?

Answer (score 0):

Another way to check month:

```
DB::table("customer_entry")->whereMonth('date', '=',$currentMonth)->select(DB::raw('COUNT(customer_id)'))->groupBy('customer_id')->havingRaw("COUNT(customer_id) > 1")->get()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this issue by different approach.
You can create separate table or add column (visited) to your login table.
Whenever user login increment the visited count by one.

### Schema

```
$table->bigIncrements('id');
$table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id')->unique();
$table->integer('visited')->default('0');
```

Increment this visited field by one whenever user login

Answer (score 0):

Maybe in this way

```
Model::selectId($userId)->whereMonth('visit', '=', $month)->count();
```

- You get the model
- Select the `user` of your model through it's ID
- Filter by month
- Make the count

With this you will get an integer **representing total of times an specific user recorded a visit**